# check the bigger file between 2 files by its file size in batch file

Tags: batch-file

Is this possible?:

I want to check my 1st.pdf and 2nd.pdf whether which of them has the bigger size. 
I'd like to add this to my code in batch file. So far this is my code:

```
@ECHO OFF

for /f "delims=" %%c IN ('dir /b "D:\AT_TestReports\CodedUI\Pdf\Int\*.pdf"') do (

IF EXIST D:\OUTPUT\INT\PDF\%%~c. (
ECHO ** file %%~c already compared
) ELSE (
IF EXIST D:\AT_TestReports\Original\Pdf\Int\%%~c.  (
fc D:\AT_TestReports\CodedUI\Pdf\Int\%%~c D:\AT_TestReports\Original\Pdf\Int\%%~c >nul && (
echo ** Identical %%~c
) || (
echo ** generating diff output file for %%~c...     
"D:\AT_TestReports\Original\Pdf\Int\%%~c" D:\OUTPUT\INT\PDF\%%~c
echo ** %%~c output file generated.
)
) ELSE (
echo ** D:\AT_TestReports\Original\Pdf\Int\%%~c file does not exist.
)
)
)

pause
```

How can I insert the comparing of file based on their file size? I want to know if my first file is bigger than my 2nd file so that i can know the proper arrangement of the parameter that i will going to pass

Comment: which to files should be compared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this: filesizes limited to under 2 GB

```
@echo off
for %%a in ("file1.pdf") do (
for %%b in ("file2.pdf") do (
   if %%~za GEQ %%~zb (echo file1 is the same or larger than file2) else (echo file1 is smaller than file2)
)
)
pause
```